# lambda function to start aws workspaces - overcome client.start_workspaces limitation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-workspaces

i have a lambda function to start all the workspaces machines in my env

Lambda Function :

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('workspaces')

def lambda_handler(event,context):
     workspaces = client.describe_workspaces()['Workspaces']
     for workspace in workspaces:
          if workspace['WorkspaceProperties']['RunningMode'] == 'AUTO_STOP':
               if workspace['State'] == 'STOPPED':
                   workspaces_id = (workspace['WorkspaceId'])
                   client.start_workspaces(
                       StartWorkspaceRequests=[
                           {
                               'WorkspaceId': workspaces_id
                           },
                        ]
                     )
```

The client.start_workspaces has a limitation of 25 workspaces per request , any idea how to overcome this ? im trying to build a robust solution for more then 25 workspaces .

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/api/API_StartWorkspaces.html#API_StartWorkspaces_RequestSyntax

Thanks in advance to the helpers

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use Paginator. Then call the client, to start the workspace workspaces."WorkSpaces.Paginator.DescribeWorkspaces"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).